# Html element to jQuery element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this:

```
$(myElement).siblings()[0].height()
```

And I cannot get it to work. `.siblings()[0]` returns pure html instead of a jquery object. How to map it to jquery again, so that I can use .height() property on it?

Comment: `$(myElement).siblings().first().height()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want:

```
$(myElement).siblings().eq(0).height()
```

Or using `.first()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$(myElement).siblings().first().height()
```